# How to ask dotnet build command to produce 64 bit artifacts

Tags: .net, .net-core, build, 64-bit

We have a `.Net core 3.1` based `web application` and we use `dotnet build` command to generate build files in CI/CD pipeline. Below is how our build command looks like -

```
dotnet build MySolution.sln -m:1  -f=netcoreapp3.1 --nologo -c Release -p Platform=x64
```

The issue is the last part in this command doesnt work - `-p Platform=x64`
We get below error -

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1005: Specify a property and its value.
Switch: -p
```

We looked at the build command [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) but didnt get any way to create 64 bit artifacts.
Is there any way to specify different platforms (x86 vs x64) to `dotnet build` command?
Please help!

Comment: You can try `dotnet build /p:Platform=x64`

Answer (score 3):

*to specify the platform use format like in msbuild cli* for e.g.:

> `dotnet build MySolution.sln --nologo -c Release /p:Platform=x64`